# Minecraft server files generating in the wrong path on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: server, jar, minecraft

So I attempted to create my own minecraft server. Upon opening the .jar file, the files seem to generate in my [myusername] folder instead of my dedicated "server" file on the desktop. How can I change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a folder with your server-version.jar in it.

Then open your terminal, type "cd your/folder/path".

Then do "sudo java -jar server-version.jar". This will create the first few files. You'll need to agree to the EULA.

Finally, start your server using the previous command or using "sudo java -Xms512M -Xmx2048M -jar server-version.jar". You can modify the minimum and maximum ram which will be allocated to your Minecraft server.

This is what it looks like in my case using the latest spigot release :

```
cd /Users/******/Desktop/Minecraft\ Server 
sudo java -jar spigot-1.16.4.jar 

// Agree to the EULA in the EULA.txt

sudo java -Xms512M -Xmx2048M spigot-1.16.4.jar
```

All the files should be in the folder you created earlier.